# Laravel 5 Image Upload Incorrect Database Path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, upload

I have been having issues with my image upload input. I am attempting to create a file upload input into my Laravel 5 project but I am running into problems with the path that is saved into the database image table.

The form is working and is posting, however, when the database saves the path to the image it is inputting: `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phptvwTYW` instead of taking just the file name.

Additionally, the file is being moved to the correct `public/img` folder.

**Code**

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    $this->createPost($request);

    $destinationpath = public_path() . '/img/';

    $filename = $request->file('image_url')->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->file('image_url')->move( $destinationpath,$filename );

    flash()->success('Your Post Has Been Created!');

    return redirect('posts');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample Controller Function currently using in my project

```
public function postCreateInternal(CreateDocumentInternalRequest $request) {
        $data_information = $request->only(['title', 'assigned_to', 'folder_id', 'document_source']);
        if ($request->hasFile('file_name') && $request->file('file_name')->isValid()) {
            $document = $request->file('file_name');
            #creating file Name
            $mytime = Carbon::now();
            $date_now = $mytime->toDateTimeString();
            $date_now = $this->prepareFileNameString($date_now);
            $document_extension = $document->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $document_name = $this->prepareFileNameString(basename($document->getClientOriginalName(), '.' . $document_extension));
            $document_fullName = $document_name . "_" . ($date_now) . "." . $document_extension;
            $data_information['file_type'] = $document->getMimeType();
            $data_information['file_size'] = $document->getSize();
            $data_information['file_name'] = $document_fullName;
            $data_information['file_download_type'] = "Internal";
            $document->move(public_path() . '/uploads/documents/', $document_fullName);
        }
        if ($pot = $this->document->create($data_information)) {
            $this->notification_admin->sendCreateDocument($data_information);
            return redirect()->route('documents')->with('success', trans('document.create.msg_success'));
//          return redirect()->route('update/document', $pot->id)->with('success', trans('document.create.msg_success'));
        }
        return redirect()->route('create/document')->with('error', trans('document.msg_error'));
    }
```

`CreateDocumentInternalRequest` basically using for File and other data validation as per Laravel 5

And View File seems to like:

```
{!! Form::open(["class"=>"form-horizontal","data-parsley-validate"=>"data-parsley-validate",'role'=>'form','files'=>true]) !!}
<div class="form-group  required {{ $errors->first('file_name', ' has-error') }}">
    {!!Form::label('file_name', trans('document.label.file_name'), array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label left-label'))!!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::file('file_name') !!}
        {!! $errors->first('file_name', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my current implementation, first i'm checking file uploaded, rename filename with current timestamp and re upload my desire location.
If you need any help my provided method let me know to improve in better way.

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple way:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('image')->move(base_path().'/public/images', $image_name);
    $post = ($request->except(['image']));
    $post['image'] = $image_name;
    Post::create($post);
    Session::flash('success_message', 'Post has been added successfully!');
    return redirect('teacher');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function profileUpdate($id)
    {

    if(!Entrust::can('profile_update_employee'))
        return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->withErrors(Config::get('constants.NA'));

    if(!Helper::getMode())
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(Config::get('constants.DISABLE_MESSAGE'));

    $employee = User::find($id);

    if(!$employee)
        return Redirect::to('employee')->withErrors(Config::get('constants.INVALID_LINK'));

    $rules = array(
        'photo' => 'image|image_size:<=2000|max:100000',
        'date_of_birth' => 'date',
        'date_of_joining' => 'date',
        'date_of_leaving' => 'date',
        'employee_code' => 'required|unique:profile,employee_code,'.$employee->Profile->id.',id'
    );


    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return Redirect::to('/employee/'.$id."#basic")->withErrors($validator);

    Activity::log('Profile updated');
    $profile = $employee->Profile ?: new Profile;
    $photo = $profile->photo;
    $data = Input::all();
    $profile->fill($data);
    if(Input::get('date_of_birth') == '')
        $profile->date_of_birth = null;
    if(Input::get('date_of_joining') == '')
        $profile->date_of_joining = null;
    if(Input::get('date_of_leaving') == '')
        $profile->date_of_leaving = null;

    if (Input::hasFile('photo') && Input::get('remove_photo') != 1) {


      $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
      $extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $file = Input::file('photo')->move('assets/user/', $employee->username.".".$extension);

      DB::insert('insert into ez_profile (id, photo) values ($id, $photo)');

      $img = Image::make('assets/user/'.$user->username.".".$extension);
      $img->resize(200, null, function ($constraint) {
      $constraint->aspectRatio();
      });
      $img->save('assets/user/'.$user->username.".".$extension);
      $profile->photo = $employee->username.".".$extension;
      } elseif(Input::get('remove_photo') == 1){
      File::delete('assets/user/'.$profile->photo);
      $profile->photo = null;
      }
      else
      $profile->photo = $photo;
      $employee->profile()->save($profile);
      return Redirect::to('/employee/'.$id.'/#basic')->withSuccess(Config::get('constants.SAVED'));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request, Post $post) { 
    $destinationpath = public_path() . '/img/';

    $filename = $request->file('image_url')->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->file('image_url')->move( $destinationpath,$filename );

    $post->create([
        'field1' => $val1,
        'imageField' => $filename,
        'field2' => $val2
        ]);

    flash()->success('Your Post Has Been Created!');

    return redirect('posts');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question.
I had to make some changes to the store and createPost functions within my controller to make this work.

For the controller I have:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
        $destinationpath = public_path() . '/img/';

        $filename = $request->file('image_url')->getClientOriginalName();

        $request->file('image_url')->move( $destinationpath,$filename );

        $this->createPost($request, $filename);

        flash()->success('Your Post Has Been Created!');

        return redirect('posts');
}


private function createPost(PostRequest $request, $new_url)
{
        $post = Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());

        $post->image_url = $new_url;

        $post->save();

        $this->syncTags($post, $request->input('tag_list'));

        return $post;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else that may be running into this same problem.
Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score -1):

its because you save before moving,

```
//before moving 
$request->file('image_url')->getPath(); // returns Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php...
```

to have the full path of your new moved file you can do this

```
//After moving
$res = $request->file('image_url')->move( $destinationpath,$filename );
$my_new_path = $res->getPath(); // returns [public_path]/img/filename.jpg
```

you can save it by update your post after moving the file, or use event to move it when saving 
look here http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993123/laravel-4-2-storing-image-path-to-database